# Lombok generate only methods skipping the field

Tags: java, lombok

Is it possible with lombok to generate only the methods related (@Getter, @Setter) to a field and not the field?

Possible use case, I have a parent class A, I have a class B that extends A. 
In class B I want to ovverride the annotations of the getters/setters of some fields of A.

Essentially I have 2 possibilities for doing this:

1. I can override the interested getter and setter adding the annotations
2. exploiting java field hiding, I redeclare the interested fields, adding the annotations over them and annotating class B with @Data (or I can also exploit @Getter @Setter).

The second solution is much more cleaner and readable then the first one.
I prefer the second solution since in some cases I would have dozens of getters/setters.
Nevertheless I would like to avoid field hiding.

What I'm looking for is something like @GenerateField(value=false).
That at compile time will not generate the field (no field hiding so) but will generate the @Getters and the @Setters of this field together with the added annotations.

Something like this:

```
@Data
public class A{
  private String id;

  private String name;
}

@Data
public class B extends A{

  @Id
  @GeneratedField(value=false)
  private String id;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you show in code what your class structure is supposed to look like and which methods you want to have available on what instances?

Comment: @luk2302 I've added some code

Comment: I think you forgot an `extends A`. What should happen if I write `A b = new B();`, is that supposed to have a `getId()` method? and which field should be affected?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes both classes are supposed to have a getId() method (due to lombok Data annotation), but the second one has the method annotated also with the Id annotation and I would like that the field of the second class is not generated at compile time, but only its methods are generated.